# Flutter: How to user a DropDownButton with provider?

Tags: flutter

I have a dropDownButton where i select the theme for the entire app. I have tried two ways of actually trying to fix this. First one was using the commented line "Provider.of(context).toggleTheme();" in the "setState". Had to make the "listen" option "false" as advised in another thread but it was not working. And the second one was to just call the "toggleTheme()" inside the "Themes.dart" in order to notify listeners that way. What would be a correct implementation for a Dropdownbutton like this.

MainScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thisismylastattempt/Misc/Themes.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = "main_screen";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}


class ThemeOptions{
  final Color themeColor;
  final ThemeType enumTheme;
  ThemeOptions({this.themeColor, this.enumTheme});

  void callParentTheme(){
    ThemeModel().changeEnumValue(enumTheme);
  }
}


class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {


  List<ThemeOptions> themes = [
    ThemeOptions(themeColor: Colors.teal, enumTheme: ThemeType.Teal),
    ThemeOptions(themeColor: Colors.green, enumTheme: ThemeType.Green),
    ThemeOptions(themeColor: Colors.lightGreen, enumTheme: ThemeType.LightGreen),
  ];

  ThemeOptions dropdownValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
     dropdownValue = themes[0];
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MainScreen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           child: DropdownButton<ThemeOptions>(
             value: dropdownValue,
             icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
             iconSize: 24,
             elevation: 16,
             style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.deepPurple
             ),
             underline: Container(
               height: 0.0,
               color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
             ),
             onChanged: (ThemeOptions newValue) {
               setState(() {
                 dropdownValue = newValue;
                 dropdownValue.callParentTheme();
                 print(newValue.themeColor);
                 //Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context).toggleTheme();
               });
             },
             items: themes.map((ThemeOptions colorThemeInstance) {
               return DropdownMenuItem<ThemeOptions>(
                 value: colorThemeInstance,
                 child: CircleAvatar(
                   backgroundColor: colorThemeInstance.themeColor,
                 ),
               );
             })
                 .toList(),
           ),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
       ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Themes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ThemeType {Teal, Green, LightGreen}

ThemeData tealTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(

  primaryColor: Colors.teal.shade700,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.teal.shade700,
  ),

);

ThemeData greenTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(

  primaryColor: Colors.green.shade700,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.green.shade700,
  ),

);

ThemeData lightGreenTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(

  primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen.shade700,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.lightGreen.shade700,
  ),

);

class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData currentTheme = tealTheme;
  ThemeType _themeType = ThemeType.Teal;

  toggleTheme() {
    if (_themeType == ThemeType.Teal) {
      currentTheme = tealTheme;
      _themeType = ThemeType.Teal;
      print('teal');
       notifyListeners();
    }

    if (_themeType == ThemeType.Green) {
      currentTheme = greenTheme;
      _themeType = ThemeType.Green;
      print('green');
       notifyListeners();
    }
    if (_themeType == ThemeType.LightGreen) {
      currentTheme = lightGreenTheme;
      _themeType = ThemeType.LightGreen;
      print('lightGreen');
       notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  ThemeType getEnumValue(){
    return _themeType;
  }

  void changeEnumValue(ThemeType newThemeType){
   _themeType = newThemeType;
   toggleTheme();
  }

}
```

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(
    create: (BuildContext context) => ThemeModel(), child: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context).currentTheme,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        initialRoute: MainScreen.id,
        routes: {
          Wrapper.id: (context) => Wrapper(),
          LoginPage.id: (context) => LoginPage(),
          Registration.id: (context) => Registration(),
          MainScreen.id: (context) => MainScreen(),
          SwitchAuthenticationState.id: (context) =>
              SwitchAuthenticationState(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by calling the `changeEnumValue` from the `Provider` in the `callParentTheme` of your `ThemeOptions`class :

```
class ThemeOptions {
  final Color themeColor;
  final ThemeType enumTheme;
  ThemeOptions({this.themeColor, this.enumTheme});

  // void callParentTheme() {
  //   ThemeModel().changeEnumValue(enumTheme);
  void callParentTheme(context) {
    Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context, listen: false).changeEnumValue(enumTheme);
  }
```

call the method with the context in your `DropDown` `onChanged` method :

```
onChanged: (ThemeOptions newValue) {
  setState(() {
    dropdownValue = newValue;
    dropdownValue.callParentTheme(context);
    print(newValue.themeColor);
  });
},
```

Hope It's help

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man, i can see now why it was not working before.